# How can I find File name in string which start with # Using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have string :

```
" testfile.txt #testfile.txt
  My new message
Filename1.doc #filename.doc"
```

How can I find file name starting with '#' and remove it from string

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: my exepected output is:

" testfile.txt 
  My new message
Filename1.doc "

Comment: is your input contain newline characters? try `Regex.Replace(str, @"#\S+", "");`

Comment: YES!! My Input contain new line character and it should remain in the output. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: try `Regex.Replace(str, @"#\S+", "");` or `Regex.Replace(str, @"#.*", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var pattern = @"\#[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\s*";
var result = Regex.Replace(
            "testfile.txt #testfile.txt My new message Filename1.doc #filename.doc",
            pattern, string.Empty);
```

result:

```
 "testfile.txt  My new message Filename1.doc "
```

Comment: Happy in helping you ^^